# garbage collection of bidirectional relationships

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have something like this:

The User:

```
public User {

    List<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
    // getter/setter

}
```

And its tasks:

```
public Task{

    private User user;
    // getter/setter

}
```

I create a new `Task` and store it into `User`:

```
var user = new User();
var task1 = new Task();
var task2 = new Task()
task1.setUser(user);
task2.setUser(user);
user.getTasks().add(task1);
user.getTasks().add(task2);
```

**Now the question:**

If I delete the the `tasks`-list from `user`:

```
user.getTasks().clear();
```

will the `tasks` be garbage collected or **do I need to remove the user instance explicitly** from all the `tasks` also (for a successfully garbage collection)?

```
task1.setUser(null);  // needed?
task2.setUser(null);  // needed?
user.getTasks().clear(); // or is this all I need
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, you do not need to do *any* of those, `gc` wise. The way garbage collector traverses live instances it already knows what is alive or not, even if you "chain" those into a recursion. No garbage collector in `openjdk` works based on the `reference counting` algorithm (were this could be a problem as far as I see). While you could both call `clear` *and* call `set(null)`, this will not matter much. Unreachable instances will still be collected.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collector should free the memory for objects which is no longer reachable. When you are calling the clear method, task objects will no longer have a reference, so they should be eligible for garbage collection even though the object user from inside it is still reachable.